# Problem with <%= yield %>, turbolinks and algolia places

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, yield, turbolinks

I have been working on this error for days and I can't solve it. I really need help. I have this code in my application.html.erb file. It was advised to me by a community member and it should be the right way to do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Neigbornow</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <%= yield :meta %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'autocomplete' %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= yield :js %>
    <%= yield :css %>

  </head>
  <body>
    <% if @user.nil? %>
      <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <% elsif user_signed_in? && @user.street.nil? %>
      <%= render partial: "layouts/header_address" %>
    <% else %>
      <%= render 'layouts/header_rest' %>
    <% end %>
    <div id="main">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This code breaks my homepage layout:

[image]

So, I played around with it, and placed <%= yield %> in the beginning of the body. Now the design looks the way I actually defined it:

[image]

But, to be honest, I don't really get the <%= yield %> rools, so I am not sure, what is happening there. Moreover I have further issues. If I use

```
<%= yield :js %>
```

this actually "breaks" my algolia autocomplete file.

```
import places from 'places.js';

const initAutocomplete = () => {
  var placesAutocomplete = places({
    container: document.getElementById('user_street'),
    templates: {
      value: function(suggestion) {
        return suggestion.name;
      }
    }
  }).configure({
    type: 'address'
  });

  placesAutocomplete.on('change', function resultSelected(e) {
    document.getElementById('user_city').value = e.suggestion.city || '';
    document.getElementById('user_zip_code').value = e.suggestion.postcode || '';
  });
};


export { initAutocomplete };
```

The autocomplete option just won't show up:

[image]

Also another thing happens, just before the redirection to next page (the one above), a modal window with errors will load, which is only supposed to show up, when the errors appear, not on redirection from a current page.

If I change the "yield"-order and delete the :js specification, then the autocomplete works.

```
<%= yield :meta %>
<%= yield %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'autocomplete' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= yield :css %>
```

But I get the following problem:

[image]

And the other one, breaking my modal with error messages.

[image]

If I refresh page manually, the modal, however, behaves as defined, with no problems.

I did some research and I think, the problem here are the turbolinks. Since I both use javascript in assets and the webpack packs (for algolia), I guess, it somehows brings my code into chaos. I tried to get rid of turbolinks in the assets as described [here](https://www.innoq.com/en/blog/rails-custom-elements-with-turbolinks-webpack/) and integrate those into my webback, but this didn't work too. I got this error message by adding

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Turbolinks::Redirection
end
```

and couldn't solve it:

```
uninitialized constant ApplicationController::Turbolinks
```

I also tried to wrap my autocomplete code into a function, as was advised from one of the members, but didn't work

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function(e){ ... })
```

I really appreciate help on this, as I can't solve it myself. Thanks

Comment: We have already been through that putting the main `yield` in your head is not an option. This issue does not really have anything to do with `yield` its more that your assets and the loading order seems like a total mess. Start by only using sprockets or webpack - not both. Check which order you stylesheets are included and if they are included more then once. Ditch turbolinks if you can't wrap your head around it.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I week of hard thinking led me to the same thoughts. The problem is, originally my rails app was created without webpacker, I added it later on. I found a tutorial on medium, on how to transfer the assists to webpacker, but this didn’t work for me. So I am lost again. Maybe you know a good tutorial online or a way of switching from assets to webpacker? This would be great!